# Comparing two NSDates constantly even outside the app

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, alarm

I decided for my first application i would create an alarm application. So far i understand to create two NSDate objects and compare them with isEqualToDate and UILocalNotifications for notifications. How do i continually compare the set date to the current date. Do i create a loop, or is there a more efficient way on Objective C? How do i continually check in the background?

[very new to objective c, sorry and thank you]

This what iv'e started:

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDate * later = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"];
NSComparisonResult result = [later compare:mile];

NSLog(@"%@", later);
NSLog(@"%@", mile);
```

Comment: Why do you need to compare dates if you have a notification set up? It has a fire date which the system takes care of.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create loops or compare dates yourself. One way to have your alarm sound could be via a local notification. A quick sample code to schedule yourself a local notification:

```
// Initialize your notification
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];

// Set the title of your notification
[notification setTitle:@"Alarm finished!"];

// Set the text of your notification
[notification setInformativeText:@"My Text"];

// Set the time and date on which the notification will be delivered (in this case 60 seconds after the current time)
[notification setDeliveryDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]];

// Set the sound, this can be either nil for no sound, NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName for the default sound)
[notification setSoundName:NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName];

// Schedule the notification
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] scheduleNotification:notification];
```

If you don't want to use a local notification but want to execute something different once your alarm finishes, you could use `NSTimer` to execute your action once the alarm fires.

Comment: Interesting, but this will trigger an interval after a time. What I'm really trying to do is trigger when the current time is the same as the set date. Any hints?

Comment: What do you need, a notification on desktop or mobile? Or do you need to trigger a NSTimer?

Comment: @JustinShulman: You can't literally do what you're asking to do. You can't run code to check the time when your app isn't running (and even if your app was running, looping to poll the time is _incredibly_ wasteful). What you can do is give the system the date at which you need to do something, via either an `NSTimer` or, if your app might stop running in the meanwhile, a local notification. The system will then check that "the current time is the same as the set date" and "trigger" your code.